# SSH to local without password

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6

We have some scripts that need to rsync without entering a password. I am trying to SSH to a local machine (itself). I cannot get it to work. It is always asking me for a password. It works fine SSH-ing to a remote machine.

I am running CentOS 6. The user's home directory is in a non-standard location (i.e. it is not under /home/$USER).

Here is what I have done to try and get this working.

I created private key using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "servername.domain"
```

without a passphrase.

copied the generated public key to  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and tried to SSH using

```
ssh servername.domain
```

and it is asking me for a password. I have tried playing with permissions of that file to no avail.

I have noticed that when I SSH using a password I get this error in the /var/log/secure log file. Not sure if this is related, but the error is as below.

```
Feb 12 09:15:34 servername unix_chkpwd[14652]: password check failed for user
```

When performing ssh -v and comparing the results of a seesion that working without prompting for a password (remote) and one that always prompts (local) I can see a few difference. The first is that the failure shows:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
```

Whereas the working session shows just the first line, the following two are not present.

Later I see:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

On the working version this is followed by:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
```

Whereas on the failing versiodn it is followed by:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

---

I have since found that SSH works when disabling selinux. I think the issue may be due to the non-standard location of the user's home directory.

Comment: Try using 'ssh -v servername.domain' to enable detailed error message.

Comment: Your sshd might be configured in a way users' .ssh directory is not searched for `authorized_keys`. You should check your `sshd_config` file as well.

Comment: @Ouki I've put debug on in the sshd config and can see that it is looking in the correct directory

Comment: @Tutul I have added output from working and failing examples.

Comment: You've said the home directories are in a non-standard location.  They're not also encrypted, by any chance?

Comment: As you have identified SELinux as an issue have a look though /var/log/audit/audit.log for AVC denied messages relating to ssh with SELinux in permissive mode (setenforce 0).

Comment: Also, you say you've verified that `sshd` is looking in the right place for `authorized_keys`, which is great: but you haven't shown us the evidence.

Comment: Backing @MadHatter wether your sshd is configured properly. You showed us that the key `id_rsa` is used as expected, but not your sshd configuration. To be precise, configuration value for:  `AuthorizedKeysFile`, `RSAAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use keys, if the perms on the `.ssh` directory and/or the `authorized_keys` files are not correct then ssh falls back to passwords if it is allowed to do so (`PasswordAuthentication Yes`).

Check that the permissions on ~./ssh are 700 and that the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys perms are 644 (or tighter).

---

As you've identified SElinux as causing the problem and you've said that the user home directory is located in a non standard location then check /var/log/audit/audit.log for relevant AVC denied messages.

You could also try relabelling the relevant directory tree

```
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_t "/path/to/homedir(/.*)?"
restorecon -r /path/to/homedir
```

Comment: Yes, the permissions are correct (700 and 600)